# How to keep the selected color of a box in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a form that gives people the option to choose between two items.
Currently, when you hover over an item, the background color changes.

```
$('.survey').hover(
        function(){ $(this).addClass('value-selected') },
        function(){ $(this).removeClass('value-selected') }
        )
```

Now I am trying to do the same but with `.focusin`:

```
        $('.survey').focusin(
            function(){ $(this).addClass('value-selected') },
            function(){ $(this).removeClass('value-selected') }
            )
```

However, unlike `.hover` this does not work.

What I would like to do is to keep the background color of the item on whichever box is selected.

```
    $('input[name="question1"]').change(function() {
        resetQuestion('question2');

        // save answer1 and answer2 values of question1 into variables
        question1Answers.answer1 = $('.answer1 input[name="question1"]').prop('checked');
        question1Answers.answer2 = $('.answer2 input[name="question1"]').prop('checked');

        if (question1Answers.answer1) { // if user select answer1 of question1, then
            $('#question2').hide(); // hide question2 box
            $('#survey-title').hide(); // hide survey title (grey box)
            $('.survey-result.bg--item1').show(); // show item1 box
            $('.survey-result.bg--item2').hide(); // hide item2 box

        } else (question1Answers.answer2) { // if user select answer2 of question1, then
            $(this).focusin('value-selected')
            $('#question2').show(); // show question2
            $('#survey-title').show(); // show survey title (grey box)
            $('.survey-result.bg--item1').hide(); // hide item1 box
            $('.survey-result.bg--item2').hide(); // hide item2 box
```

I'm relatively new to jquery so I don't understand what I'm doing wrong and I can't use a plugin to do this. Any help /ideas would be appreciated.

### Edit:

I am now able to get the box to stay the right color thanks to Suraj Menon below pointing me in the right direction. However, now the hover function isn't available.

```
    $('.survey').hover(
        function(){ $(this).addClass('value-selected') },
        function(){ $(this).removeClass('value-selected') }
        )
    $('survey').on('click', function() {
            $('survey').removeClass('value-selected');
            $(this).addClass('value-selected')  
        })
```

Comment: add related html

Answer (score 0):

On click of any box you can add a class called "active" to it and in the css you can define a background color for it. Now to get the toggle, onclick of any of the boxes remove the ".active" class (all boxes are without active class now) and then re-assign it to the box which was clicked.

You can pass in the event parameter to the button to know which button was clicked.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I was able to get the color to stick but my hover isn't working as shown in my question edit. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to solve this with the following code which combines the hover and click function:

```
    $('.survey').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).addClass('value-selected');
        }, function() {
            if(!$(this).hasClass('clicked') ){
                $(this).removeClass('value-selected');
            }
        }
    );

    $('.survey').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        e.stopPropagation;
        $('.clicked:not(:hover)').removeClass('clicked');
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
    });
```

I'm sure it can be simplified, but it does what it needs to.